# Convert specific number in file in awk

Tags: linux, awk, text-formatting

I have a big problem. I have a file like:

```
   18   13    8    5        3       1.715   2.845   1.046  -5.607  -0.000   0.000
   38   34   29   24        3       1.715   2.845   1.046  -5.607  -0.000   0.000
   12   14    9    5        3       1.715   2.845   1.046  -5.607  -0.000   0.000
   34   29   24   30        3       1.715   2.845   1.046  -5.607  -0.000   0.000
   14    9    5    3        3       1.715   2.845   1.046  -5.607  -0.000   0.000
   13    8    5    3        3       1.715   2.845   1.046  -5.607  -0.000   0.000
   34   29   24   28        3       1.590   4.770   0.000  -6.360  -0.000   0.000
   13    8    5    7        3       1.590   4.770   0.000  -6.360  -0.000   0.000
   14    9    5    7        3       1.590   4.770   0.000  -6.360  -0.000   
    7    5    3    6        3       0.628   1.883   0.000  -2.510  -0.000   0.000
    7    5    3    4        3       0.628   1.883   0.000  -2.510  -0.000   0.000
    7    5    3    2        3       0.979   2.937   0.000  -3.916  -0.000   0.0000.000
   14    9    5    8        3      -6.458   0.810   5.682  -0.033  -0.000   0.000
   13    8    5    9        3      -6.458   0.810   5.682  -0.033  -0.000   0.000
   34   29   24   22        3      -6.458   0.810   5.682  -0.033  -0.000   0.000
etc
```

And I use gsub to replace specific number to specific number like:

```
awk '{ gsub(/1/, "9"); gsub(/2/, "8"); gsub(/3/, "6"); gsub(/4/, "7"); gsub(/5/, "4"); gsub(/6/, "10"); gsub(/7/, "5"); gsub(/82/, "92"); gsub(/83/, "91"); gsub(/84/, "94"); gsub(/85/, "93"); gsub(/86/, "97"); gsub(/87/, "95"); gsub(/88/, "96"); etc.....
print $1, $2, $3, $4 }' proba | tee proba2
```

But I have a problem. I want to replace for example 111 to 45, so I use gsub and have 45 in my document, then in my script I use again gsub and replace 4 to 76, and this replace 4 to 76, but also 45 to 765!! - I dont want that.

I try this code, but it doesnt work

```
awk '{ gsub(/ 1 /, " 9 "); gsub(/ 2 /, " 8 "); gsub(/ 3 /, " 6 "); gsub(/ 4 /, " 7 "); gsub(/ 5 /, " 4 "); gsub(/ 6 /, " 10 "); gsub(/ 7 /, " 5 "); gsub(/ 8 /, " 23 "); gsub(/ 9 /, " 3 "); gsub(/ 10 /, " 11 "); gsub(/ 11 /, " 12 ");  print $1, $2, $3, $4 }' proba | tee proba2
```

I want to replace whole numbers. I don't want `12` become `98`. I want to replace whole number in four columns (print $1, $2, $3, $4). Input format for example: `22 56 3 75` Output format for example `35 82 91 5` It's good to have the same format as the input, but this is not so much important. (I can edit format a little after that by myself)

Comment: I want to replace whole numbers. I dont want 12 become 98. I want to replace whole number in four columns (prinst $1, $2, $3, $4).

Input format for example:
22   56    3    75
Output format for example
35   82   91   5


Its good to have the same format as the input, but this is not so much important(I can edit format a little after that by myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to create a file, e.g. `replace.txt` that contains the replacements, old value in column 1, new value in column 2, like this

```
1 9
2 8
3 6
4 7
5 4
6 10
7 5
82 92
83 91
84 94
85 93
86 97
87 95
88 96
```

Assuming your data file is `data.txt`, you can use this AWK script:

```bsh
awk 'NR==FNR { t[$1]=$2; next;} # fill translation table from first file
{ for(i=1;i<5;i++) { # process columns 1..4
        if ($i in t) { # replacement available
                $i=t[$i]; # replace field only once
        }
  }
  print $1, $2, $3, $4;
  # or if you want all columns:
  # $1=$1 # this makes sure unmodified lines get the new format
  # print # print all fields after modification
}' replace.txt data.txt
```

With your input this generates

```
18 13 8 4
38 34 29 24
12 14 9 4
34 29 24 30
14 9 4 6
13 8 4 6
34 29 24 28
13 8 4 5
14 9 4 5
5 4 6 10
5 4 6 7
5 4 6 8
14 9 4 8
13 8 4 9
34 29 24 22
```

or with the alternative output

```
18 13 8 4 3 1.715 2.845 1.046 -5.607 -0.000 0.000
38 34 29 24 3 1.715 2.845 1.046 -5.607 -0.000 0.000
12 14 9 4 3 1.715 2.845 1.046 -5.607 -0.000 0.000
34 29 24 30 3 1.715 2.845 1.046 -5.607 -0.000 0.000
14 9 4 6 3 1.715 2.845 1.046 -5.607 -0.000 0.000
13 8 4 6 3 1.715 2.845 1.046 -5.607 -0.000 0.000
34 29 24 28 3 1.590 4.770 0.000 -6.360 -0.000 0.000
13 8 4 5 3 1.590 4.770 0.000 -6.360 -0.000 0.000
14 9 4 5 3 1.590 4.770 0.000 -6.360 -0.000
5 4 6 10 3 0.628 1.883 0.000 -2.510 -0.000 0.000
5 4 6 7 3 0.628 1.883 0.000 -2.510 -0.000 0.000
5 4 6 8 3 0.979 2.937 0.000 -3.916 -0.000 0.0000.000
14 9 4 8 3 -6.458 0.810 5.682 -0.033 -0.000 0.000
13 8 4 9 3 -6.458 0.810 5.682 -0.033 -0.000 0.000
34 29 24 22 3 -6.458 0.810 5.682 -0.033 -0.000 0.000
```

Comment: (opinion based spoiler) : I would have use `$i in t` instead of `t[$i] != ""`